# How to start a new ember project

Tags: ember.js

I've been asked to use ember again, at it's been a while since i left it;

I was reading that, like in the past, ember-cli is the recommended way to start a new ember project;
But my concern is: the official stable version of ember-cli uses an outdated ember version; on the other hand the ember-cli with the latest ember (2.22) is a beta;

can someone share his experience in order to understand the preferred way to deal with ember projects right now?

Answer (score 4):

You can use ember-cli 1.13.13 with Ember 2.2. Just after typing ember new, edit your bower.json and package.json appropriately and run bower install and npm install.

Comment: To my experience the 2.2 beta of Ember CLI is pretty stable. But definitely start with Ember v2.0, even when using Ember CLI 1.13.